# Convert IST to ISO DATE Format in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am passing a date from a **datepicker** `(Wed Mar 23 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST) )` and I want it as **`ISODate`**`("2016-03-22T08:47:35.952Z")` format

How to convert IST date to ISO date in javascript?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the IST date format is, but I'm curious as to how you get from 00:00:00 to 08:47:35.952?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly IST is Indian Standard Time. Timezones!

Comment: @RohitAgre is a timezone really specific to 47 minutes, 35 seconds and 952 milliseconds though?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var test = new Date("Wed, 23 Mar 2016 00:00:00 +0530");
test.toISOString()
```

Comment: I am using the method but it always returns on day less than the actual date. here is my code -> this.date = new Date(); this.date2 = this.date.toISOString();